# How to display the username of the user that created the article in Django

Tags: python, django

I login with my username. And I created some articles. 
How can I display the username in each article I created?

This is my models.py:

```
class hire_article(models.Model):
    hiring = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey(category)
    localwork = models.ForeignKey(localwork)
    salary = models.ForeignKey(salary)
    exp_year = models.ForeignKey(exp_year)
    degree = models.ForeignKey(degree)
```

This is my views.py

```
def post(request):
    if user.is_authenticated:
        hire_article.whopost= user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = postform(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/hire/thanks/')
        else:
            print (form.errors)
            # return render(request, '/accounts/login.html', {'notlogin': True})

    else:
        form = postform()

    return render(request, 'companys/post.html', {'form': form})
```

This is my template

```
{{hire_article.hiring}}<br>
{{hire_article.category}}<br>
{{hire_article.localwork}}<br>
{{hire_article.salary}}<br>
{{hire_article.exp_year}}<br>
{{hire_article.degree}}<br>
```

Comment: Your model doesn't have a field called `whopost` though. Also, it doesn't seem like you're saving the creator at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ref a ForeignKey to User Model in your "hire_article".
So that you can use "request.user.id" as the filter in your view.py and pass the result to front-end.

Comment: i add "whopost = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)" in my models

Comment: Then you can use "articles = hire_article.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)" to get articles which created by the user in your view.py.

Comment: No, my mean is display username in article. Not article of username creat.

Comment: If you exactly added "whopost" in your model and import into view.py, then you can get user name by "whopost.name".

Comment: Hey bustta, can you show me the code in view.py. ? thank you!